# SingalR access global.asax variable

Tags: c#, webforms, signalr

I'm trying from my hub class to access an Application variable created in my global.asax. I keep getting a complication error stating that the name "Application" does not exist in the current context. Can anyone help?

Global.asax

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{

    Application["aString"] = "Test";


}
```

ChatHub.cs

```
public void testMethod()
    {
        String aString = (String)Application["aString"];
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `HttpContext.Current.Application`